# console.log not working with nodejs socket.io project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

This is regarding the following small demo project: 
https://github.com/lockerfish/nodejs-socket-io-chat/blob/master/chat.js

Has a console.log in it (line 32 of chat.js) that I can never trigger. I also cannot get any other console.log to output anything. The chat server works as expected... but I can't get console log to work at all. Quite simply, nothing gets output to console, period.

Why would this be? Does it have something to do with nodejs? Maybe with socket.io? Obviously I'm new to this but not to javascript in general. What am I missing here?

Comment: What does `alert(console.log);​` give you?

Comment: @Aesthete - nothing. It's as if it never gets reached. I tried sticking it after lines 32 and 35 and before line 41. The app works... just not console output (or alerts). So strange.

Comment: Have you tried putting it in other functions? Have you tried breaking the execution in the browser with a breakpoint? Are you sure the function is being called?

Comment: Put it (console.log... alert returns 'undefined') in each function and condition in chat.js. The functions are def being called because I can alter the text of the `emit` functions and see them change. However, console calls on either side of those `emits` do nothing. I'll try setting a breakpoint and seeing what happens.

Comment: Putting console.log into the js on the javascript portion of template.html of that project works fine... just not when they are in client.js

Comment: Try `window.console.log()` and see if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's just that you are looking for the console.log output in the web-browser and not in the terminal. When I tried it it worked fine.

All the console.logs in the scripts that node runs is outputted to the window/terminal that starts the script.

Answer (score 0):

In the end nothing worked for me, to log output, I ended up having to send it to the client and log it there.

```
server
socket.emit('test', logMessage)

client
socket.on('test', message=>{
console.log(message)
})
```